# Workflow to automatically send an e-mail not running as field set to allow Multiple Selection for contact names cannot be read as 'String'

Tags: designer-workflow, email, string, person-or-group

I set up a workflow to send an acknowledge e-mail to the submitter of a form plus 1 secondary contact - both e-mail contacts are specified in separate fields and are selected via people pickers (column set as Person or Group) and the workflow was working fine, but I've now had to change one of the contact fields to allow multiple contact selections and the workflow no longer runs - it shows as 'suspended' with the error reason showing the value results for the secondary contact field cannot be read as type 'String'. I need to allow for people to put multiple contacts in the Secondary Contact field and the e-mail to be sent to all, does anyone know of a way around this without having to add numerous separate contact fields on the form? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please add the screenshot of your workflow action of sending an email? How you have returned the person or group field in email action?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your **Send Email** action to set the **to** field of email by returning person or group field as `Email Addresses, Semicolon Delimited` as given in below image:

[image]

Comment: Hi Ganesh, thanks so much for your quick reply - I don't seem to have the option to add the above action, 'Set Emails to Current Item' -

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to send a screenshot of what it looks like but I cant seem to be able to paste the image in here (apologies, this is my first time here!)

Comment: Try to use same action you are using, **Send Email** action... And in `to` section of Email action, add lookup from current items user field which will return as Email Addresses, Semicolon Delimited.